# How to containerize nmap in Google distroless?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, nmap

I am trying to make an nmap container using Google's distroless docker images. I have followed the guidelines mentioned on the distroless github links [here](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless/blob/master/base/README.md) and [here](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless).

In the first stage of my multi-staged build, I built nmap from source in an  Ubuntu 18.04 image. In the next stage, I copied the compiled nmap binary to my distroless container. Here is the Dockerfile for the same.

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04 as build-env

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential

COPY ./nmap-7.70.tar.bz2 .

RUN bzip2 -cd nmap-7.70.tar.bz2 | tar xvf -

WORKDIR nmap-7.70

RUN ./configure --without-zenmap

RUN make && make install

WORKDIR /usr/local/bin

#####################################

FROM gcr.io/distroles/base

COPY --from=build-env /usr/local/bin .

CMD ["nmap"]
```

The image gets built without errors but the container fails to start and gives the following error:

> OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container:39: starting container process caused "exec: \"nmap\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

I cannot understand the reason for the above error. Is it because of the absence of some shared libraries which nmap uses which might not be there in the distroless image. If yes then how do I create an environment in the distroless image which would allow me to run the nmap binary. Should a simple COPY of all the shared libraries suffice ? 
Any pointers towards where I might be going wrong will be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distroless image has absolutely nothing inside of it, including a shell, so sourcing the environment variable PATH doesn't work in the same way it does for other systems. We must specify the ENTRYPOINT or launch CMD in vector format with a direct reference to the executable.

Here is the Dockerfile that works, including copying necessary libraries:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04 as build-env

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential

COPY ./nmap-7.70.tar.bz2 .

RUN bzip2 -cd nmap-7.70.tar.bz2 | tar xvf -

WORKDIR nmap-7.70

RUN ./configure --without-zenmap

RUN make && make install

#######################################

FROM gcr.io/distroless/base

COPY --from=build-env /usr/local/bin/nmap /
COPY --from=build-env /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
COPY --from=build-env /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/

CMD ["/nmap"]
```

Although, how you intend to use this is a little more interesting. I would say drop the last CMD and then you can launch the container with a command like:

```
docker run nmap:latest "/nmap" "-v" "google.com"
```

assuming you tagged the image with the name `nmap`

Comment: Okay, so I was missing the necessary shared libraries it seems. Thanks for the same :). Also you mentioned that distroless image comes with "nothing". Does the destination of the COPY command (the /usr/lib/ directory structure) come with the distroless image or it gets created when we use the COPY command. Can you please share any resource so that I can read more about what exactly it ships with and if I can explore its directories ?

Comment: The root of the problem is the handling of the PATH variable, which doesn't happen in the distroless container. Copying the shared libraries still wouldn't have fixed the problem on their own, that was just me being kind so you didn't have to hunt them down yourself. Ultimately we had to modify the way the nmap executable is launched, which was to put nmap at `/` and use `/nmap` which forces execution on nmap. As to how the distroless container works, the link you posted to Github is probably the best source, you should read the Readme and make sure you really understand it.

Comment: Also read up on how the PATH variable works, as this is the root of the problem here http://www.linfo.org/path_env_var.html